# Комплексные числа Unity и System.Numerics

Tags: c#, unity3d

Искал возможность определять частоту звука с микрофона и наткнулся на преобразование Фурье. Но там все решения идут через комплексные числа, а Unity, похоже, их не поддерживает. Во всяком случае, System.Numerics точно не находит.

Вопрос - есть ли некая замена или возможность импортировать это в Unity?

Comment: Как же не поддерживает? [Структура Complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: <зануда>А вообще встроенные классы комплексных чисел медленные, пишите свой. И своё преобразование сразу. http://e-maxx.ru/algo/fft_multiply тут в комментариях есть содеражительные сообщения об ускорении в 4 раза при замене на самописные реализации</зануда>

Comment: Снова здравствуйте. Вы можете добавлять в проект свои dll и подключать их. То есть если Unity не находит System.Numerics, вы можете зайти в папку с dll, скопировать этот dll и вставить его в папку Resources в папке проекта. К тому же, вы можете написать свой класс для работы с комплексными числами, как уже сказали выше.

Comment: @pavel: Или может быть стоит не писать велосипед, а взять нормальный оптимизирующий компилятор? Это если мы говорим о C++. Для C# я не помню случая, чтобы самописные структуры данных были существенно лучше стоковых (но может быть, я недостаточно копался в алгоритмах).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй тогда скачать эту библиотеку https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/.
System.Numerics есть в .Net 4.0. Какую версию поддерживает Mono сейчас можно узнать так Debug.Log(System.Enviroment.Version).